# How to find R package for function referenced in https://www.rdocumentation.org

Tags: r, package

I am trying to learn how to do math in R. I found the following [website](https://www.rdocumentation.org) but it does not specify which package certain functions are bundled in.

For example, I am trying to run the example on Taylor Series. On the website, it gives a code snippet near the bottom of the [page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/taylor):

```
taylor(sin, 0, 4)
```

I am getting the following output:

> Error in taylor(sin, 0, 4) : could not find function "taylor"

Then, I wanted to check what the official documentation says about the function, so I entered

```
?taylor
```

and got the following:

> No documentation for ‘taylor’ in specified packages and libraries:

So, experienced users of R, is https://www.rdocumentation.org reputable? If you use it, how can you find which package you need to install in order to use certain functions?

Comment: It says at the top of the page: "From pracma v1.9.9
by HwB" so I'm guessing it's the pracma package.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the url itself: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/taylor

The page itself also specified the package from which that function originate.

In any case you’ll see that it is from the **pracma** package. Hope that’s helpful!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I installed pracma, but when I reran the code snippet, it produced the same error. Do I need to specify that the function belongs to the pracma class?

Comment: You’ll need to do: library(pracma) to load it into your environment before calling the function.

Comment: thank you so much! it works now. Will accept your answer once the system allows me to after 6 minutes.

Comment: No problem! Either run library(pracma) before calling any functions from that library like I suggested above; or you can do pracma::taylor() and that will work too. As a good practice I would advise you to do the first!

Answer (score 1):

There is an [R package called `sos`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sos/versions/2.0-0) that can help you search rapidly through packages for a keyword. You can try running the following code and see that it outputs a single match, the `pracma` package that others have mentioned here.

```
install.packages("sos")
library(sos)
findFn("taylor(sin, 0, 4)")
```

Output looks like:
[image]